# Qt5.10.1ですべてのQtQuickアプリケーションがクラッシュしてしまう

Tags: qt5

Qt5.10.1ですべてのQtQuickアプリケーションがクラッシュしてしまいます。同じような問題に遭遇した経験のある方がいらっしゃいましたらお力を貸していただければと思います。
【環境】
・Qtバージョン：Qt5.10.1 MSVC 2017 64bit
・コンパイラ：Microsoft Visual C++ Compier 15.0(amd64)

【現象】
・QtQuickアプリケーションの実行時、例外終了する。例外詳細は下記画像。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
・QtQuickソースコードは、Qt提供のサンプルと新規アプリケーション作成時に提示されるQt Quick Application -Swipe と - Scrollを変更することなくそのまま使用。すべての場合で例外終了する。
・QtWidgetアプリケーションは実行可能
・数週間前まではQt提供QtQuickサンプルの実行はできていたが、ある日から実行できなくなった。（特にPCに変更を加えた記憶はないです。）

【試したこと】
・PC再起動
・QtCreatorの再起動
・Qt5.10.1、VisualStudio2017の再インストール
・QtCreatorからではなく、EXEを直接実行
以上を試してみましたが、結果は変わらず例外終了します。

現在QtQuickの勉強をはじめたばかりです。サンプルプログラムを漁っていたのですが、本エラーが解決できず困っております。何かわかる方がおられましたらどのような情報でもよいので教えていただければと思います。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 現象を見るとnullポインタ参照して例外発生でしょう。この辺の記事を参考にデバッグ実行してみては？ [Qt+MSVCでビルドする時にQtCreatorのデバッガを使う方法](https://www.slideshare.net/chi9rin/qt-creator-msvc-microsoft)、[（Windows）Qtの開発環境を構築（Qtのインストール）](http://peanutice.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/19/%EF%BC%88Windows%EF%BC%89Qt%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)、[Qtのプログラムをデバッグできない](http://louis-needless.hatenablog.com/entry/cannot-debug-qt)、[Visual StudioでQtをデバッグする](http://atsushi4.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/12/20/125408)

Comment: kunif様コメントをどうも有難うございました。無事解決いたしました。原因はCPU内蔵GPUのドライバが古かったことの様です。QtCreatorでデバッグ実行を行ってはいたのですが、QtCreator自体がクラッシュしておりました。そこで、VirtualStudioでQtプロジェクトを読み込みデバッグを行いました。すると、「ig9icd64.dll」というDLLで例外が投げられておりました。こちらグラフィック関連のDLLでしたので、ドライバの更新を行ったところQtQuickプログラムが実行できました。助言頂きどうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問投稿者です。無事解決しました。
問題の原因と対処方法を以下に記します。

【原因】
CPU内蔵GPUのドライバが古かったこと
【解決方法】
ディスプレイアダプターのドライバ更新（Intel(R)HD Graphics 520を使用しています。）
【詳細】
VirtualStudioでQtプロジェクトを読み込みデバッグを行いました。（QtCreatorでデバッグ実行を行ってはいたのですが、QtCreator自体がクラッシュしておりました。）すると、「ig9icd64.dll」というDLLで例外が投げられておりました。こちらグラフィック関連のDLLでしたので、ドライバの更新を行ったところQtQuickプログラムが実行できました。助言頂きどうもありがとうございました。

Comment: 直接コメントの内容を「個別の回答」として投稿してもらった方が、他のユーザーが参照した時の助けになると思いますので、ぜひ [編集] で反映してみてください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。2回目の質問であまり使い方がわかっていませんでした。修正いたします。